# How to revoke JWT Bearer Token in .net core API

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have implemented  JWT Bearer token base authentication and authorization. I am using the below code for destroying the JWT token or logout the current user but it's not working.

```
//var claim = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims;
            // var users = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            //  var identity = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            // foreach (var item in claim)
            // {
            //     identity.RemoveClaim(item);
            // }

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @SumitRawat.  In what way is your code not working?  What result are you getting?  What result do you expect?

Comment: I maybe wrong here so if someone else knows better please leave a comment.  I thought JWT Bearer tokens should be revoked client side?

Comment: Yes @DavidLee i want to revoke JWT bearer token from server . In above code i am just tring to remove claims of the user

Comment: is there any way to ivalidate token or change the expiry date into past?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I revoke a JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919067/how-can-i-revoke-a-jwt-token)

Comment: @SumitRawat View my link above, seems like this is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: There is also this reference: https://forums.asp.net/t/2023270.aspx?How+to+revoke+invalidate+Bearer+token+in+Asp+Net+WebApi+2+2+when+using+OAuth says there is not built in functionality.

Comment: Everywhere it is showing that it's not easy to do but my actual problem is that when i am changing the password after that token is generated only by the previous credential

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to cancel/revoke a JWT token during user's logout, it is not straightforward, but there is a workaround to that. You can try following the steps below:

- Set a reasonable expiration time on tokens
- Delete the stored token from client side upon log out
- Have DB of no longer active tokens that still have some time to live
- Query provided token against The Blacklist on every authorized request

I am also pasting 2 links below that myself found very helpful:

- [How to log out when using JWT](https://medium.com/devgorilla/how-to-log-out-when-using-jwt-a8c7823e8a6)
- [Canceling JWT tokens in .NET Core](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2018/04/25/canceling-jwt-tokens-in-net-core/)