# Approaches for logout functionality in Spring Boot app (Spring Security + JWT)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I create Spring Boot + Spring Security app with JWT authentication and it works something like this:

- client sends username, password to the login endpoint;
- server checks if the provided credentials are valid and return a token;
- client sends the token with every future request.

It's based on [this example](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) and approach for logout functionality which author suggest - just remove JWT token on client-side. I don't think that is good idea, and I'd like to implement it on back-end.

As I understand I need to remove JWT token of user which call logout REST method on server-side, after that when this user will call other REST methods he should get responses with 403 error. I investigated ways how can I add this feature and didn't find any appropriate solution.

Here are details of my implementation (there may be some differences from the example from the link above):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, HEALTH_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        setFilterProcessesUrl(LOGIN_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}

public class SecurityConstants {
    public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
}
```

Comment: One option is to just revoke the JWT token.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919067/how-can-i-revoke-a-jwt-token