# Create custom method to disable JWT Token in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-rest

I have created Spring Boot application using Spring Security and JWT. I want to write a custom method to revoke a JWT Token, that was created and given to a user.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Please share the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I revoke a JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919067/how-can-i-revoke-a-jwt-token)