# How to invalidate JWT token after the user is not being active for amount of time

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I want to invalidate the JWT on the server side automatically after the user being inactive for 30 mins.

I know how to set a validity period for a JWT, but this will invalidate the token whether the user is active or not.

So I ***ONLY*** want to invalidate the token if the user is not active for 30 minutes.

Framework: Spring

Comment: What is the way you define `user is not active`?

Comment: @hoangdv Not opening the web app tab

Answer (score 1):

A JWT Token is valid from the period it is issued by the token issuer (the *iat* claim) until it expires (the *exp* claim).

In a distributed system, where there is a token issuer (the authorization server) and an application that *accepts* tokens (the resource server), the resource server determines if the token has expired by ensuring that the token is within the valid period - the range between the iat and exp claims.

If you wanted a way to force a token to be revoked and should no longer be accepted, even within it's valid date range, you are putting a dependency on the resource servers to have to check a token revocation list to get the status of the token. Whilst there are ways that it can be achieved, and this thread goes into details - [How can I revoke a JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919067/how-can-i-revoke-a-jwt-token), it's generally thought the overhead for managing this **reliably** is more trouble then it's worth and a better solution is to use short lived tokens, e.g. 10 mins (or whatever works for you), and have your application that requires a token to access the resource server generate a new token shortly before the expiry time.

Comment: How this answer solves the problem of the INACTIVE user?