# IdentityServer, strategy to invalidate/revoke jwt token

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

What are the options for revoking / invalidation JWTs

I have this situation in which I have to revoke or invalidate a JWT, and from what I've researched it seems that IdentityServer cannot do that.

What are some strategies to invalidate a JWT ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism for revocation, but you can store previously issued tokens and record their revocation status. This means that every time a JWT token is validated, you'll need to look it up in your token list and see if it's revoked or not.

See also: [How can I revoke a JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919067/how-can-i-revoke-a-jwt-token)

Comment: The tokens are not stored anywhere, and no claim is stored in the token to identify it, this was a business requirment, and also I'm limited with not being allowed to store any information regarding jwt